# Strange roots expansion and guessed estimation of the magnitude of a root

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image: Problem]

1. > What expansion happened to the roots? Looks like a series but it can't be? It is a root not a function, indeed $a$ should be a parameter? Furthermore, even if it was considered as a function, what type of expansion is it? Taylor?
2. > How do we know that $z_-<1$? Surely we know that $z_-<a$ but how can we conclude that it is smaller than $1$? Afterall all we know is that $a>1$.

**EDIT**

The text is:

"Compute the integral $$I = \int_C\frac{dz}{(z^2-2az+1)}$$ where $a$ is real, $a>1$ and $C$ is the unit circle. This is an integral over the complex plane, with the contour being the unit circle. The only singularities of the integrand are located at the roots of the denominator, i.e. at $$z_{\pm} = a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 1}$$ Given the conditions of $a$, we can expand those roots as $$z_{\pm} = a \pm a\left(1-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^{1/2} = a \pm (a-\frac{1}{2a}+ ...)$$ Both roots are real and $z_+ > 1$ whereas $z_- <1$. This implies that only $z_-$ lies within the contour! The singularity at $z_-$ is a simple pole, with residue..."

Comment: if you would write the problem in words instead of posting a picture, i would possibly be able to help you.

Comment: Binomial series for $(1 + x)^{1/2}$, with $x = -a^{-2}$. That's the Taylor expansion of that function too. The product of the two zeros is $1$, so if $z_+ > 1$, it follows that $z_- = \frac{1}{z_+} \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @gt6989b Is it hard to read or it doesn't load? I will write it down

Comment: @DanielFischer , thank you. So can someone consider the roots as two functions in $a$? I thought they were to be considered as parameters only

Comment: @DanielFischer , I don't understand why they never write these little comments. To be honest maybe it was obvious but surely not for me. Thankyou! You can write it down as an answer if you mind

Comment: @Euler_Salter i cannot read pictures because of domain restrictions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used generalized binomial expansion.  Specifically, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) and a few lines down will give you the exact expansion for $\sqrt{1+x}$.

Secondly, note that

$$z_- =\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{8a^3}+\frac{1}{16a^5}+\dots<\frac1{2a}+\frac1{4a^2}+\frac1{8a^3}+\dots=\frac1{2a-1}<1$$

whenever $a>1$.

Comment: I think I give up on maths. How does even someone find $\binom{1/2}{k}$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter It explains how to expand it as a product.  Do see the link.

Comment: @Euler_Salter For example, $$\binom{1/2}2=\frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)}{2!}=-\frac18$$which happens to be up there.

Comment: yeah but what about $\binom{1/2}{0}$? In the numerator it should have factors up until $(1/2 - (0-1)) = (1/2+1)$ which instead never happens as you should have $(1/2)(1/2-1)..$

Comment: @Euler_Salter It is defined to be the case that $\binom n0=1$ for all $n$, regardless.

Comment: it makes sense. What about your last line? Shouldn't it be $-\frac{1}{16a^5}$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter When you chose $z_-$, all the signs flipped.

Comment: okay but how can two consecutive terms have the same sign?

Comment: @Euler_Salter What do you mean?  The sequence above is clearly alternating.

Comment: in the last line should be $-\left(\frac{1}{8a^3}-\frac{1}{16a^5}\right)$, right?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Oh right, nice catch!

Comment: so your last line is saying that $z_-<\frac{1}{2a}<1$ r? sorry for being pedantic

Comment: @Euler_Salter No, its fine.  And yes, that is what it is saying.

Comment: hold on, on Wikipedia it says $\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+..$ but if you plug in $x=-a^{-2}$ you should get $\sqrt{1-a^-2} = 1-\frac{1}{2a^2}-\frac{1}{8a^4}-\frac{1}{16a^6}-..$ which is different from your result!

Comment: @Euler_Salter Ah!  Look at me, full of little mistakes.  So sorry, but then the answer is so much clearer, right?

Comment: not sure! Indeed you have $z_- = a-a\sqrt{1-a^{-2}}$ hence you need to do the following: $z_- = a-a(1-\frac{1}{2a^2}-\frac{1}{8a^4}-\frac{1}{16a^6}-..) $ which gives $z_- =a-a+\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{8a^3}+\frac{1}{16a^5}+..$ which gives $z_- =\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{8a^3}+\frac{1}{16a^5}+.. $ which I am not sure it's less than one

Comment: @Euler_Salter You missed a bracket at the end, and let me think this over

Comment: @Euler_Salter Ok, so I've filled in the missing step with the geometric series.  DO take a look.

Comment: thank you! Even though I think you made a little typo too as it should be $\frac{1}{1-2a}$ but it does makes sense now!

Comment: @Euler_Salter No, I think I did the geometric series part correctly at the least.  XD

Comment: hopefully ahah but shouldn't it be $1+\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{(2a)^2}+\frac{1}{(2a)^3}+..=\frac{1}{1-(2a)}$? so that we have $\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{(2a)^2}+\frac{1}{(2a)^3}+..=\frac{1}{1-(2a)}-1 = \frac{2a}{1-2a}$ ?

Comment: @Euler_Salter You have it wrong.  It should be $\frac1{1-1/2a}$

Comment: okay I must have dementia, thank you!!

Comment: @Euler_Salter Don't worry, we **all** make mistakes.